# What is the best way to declare a global variable in cakePHP

Tags: php, oop, cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I am learning cakePHP 1.26.
I got a Controller which got two functions.
I was thinking to make $myVariable a global variable so that both functions in the controllers can share it, but I am not sure if this is the best way to declare a global variable in cakePHP:

```
class TestingController extends AppController {  
     var $myVariable="hi there";

    function hello(){
     if($newUser){echo $myVariable;}
      }

     function world(){
      if($newUser=="old"){$myVariable="hi my friends";}
      }
 }
```

Please help if you could.

---

edited reason:

Hi Aircule,

I have altered a little bit to the code and followed your suggestion, but the value of myVariable was not changed at all:

```
class TestingController extends AppController {  
         var $myVariable="hi there";

        function hello(){
         echo $this->myVariable;
          }

         function world(){
          $this->myVariable="hi my friends";
          }

         function whatValue(){
         echo $this->myVariable;  // still output "hi there"
        }

     }
```

Comment: Why are you not using the latest version of cake (1.3.2)?

Comment: @ Aircule. I have been learning cakePHP 1.26 for a few weeks, and I am more familiar with this version.

Comment: This is not a global variable, but rather a class variable. If you really wanted a global in cake, you would use Nik's suggestion regarding Configure::

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look on Configure class. You can Configure::write('var', $value) or Configure::read('var') and this is accessible on all parts of the application i.e. you can define variable in AppController::beforeFind() and you can access it in Model, View and all controllers of course.

But for your case the best answer is Class variables describes in the answer above. :)

Answer (score 6):

```
class TestingController extends AppController {  
     var $myVariable="hi there";

    function hello(){
     if($newUser){echo $this->myVariable;}
      }

     function world(){
      if($newUser=="old"){$this->myVariable="hi my friends";}
      }
 }
```

(note that as it is $newUser is undefined when you call the methods).

You should read this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: @ Aircule. Is it {$this->myVariable;} or {$this->$myVariable;} 
Do I need to add a dollar sign before myVaraible?

Comment: You use `$this->myVariable` and `$this->myFunction()` when you are accessing a class variable or method.

Comment: Have you taken a look at [Bake](http://book.cakephp.org/view/113/Code-Generation-with-Bake) ?

Comment: Just to note, this is not cakePHP specific. This is an essential feature of PHP or any OOP language. Also, I'd use "private" instead of "var" for the member variable declaration.

Comment: @ Aircule. I have followed your suggestion, but the value of $myVariable still did not get changed by {$this->myVariable="hi my friends";}

Comment: @kwokwai It should have been; at least for that particular instance of the object. I suspect it's not changing because it doesn't reach that point in the code, since `$newUser` is undefined and the `if` statement evaluates to false.